# Has another command instead of type in PHPUnit Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I was testing my application using PHPUnit and Selenium Webdriver.

I use `type` command to test some of the input type.

Eg `$this->type("css=#input", "type something");`

So, I want to know it have another `command` instead of `type` in PHPUnit Selenium Webdriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can select a input element, and use `value()` function to type something.
Example:

```
$password=$this->byCssSelector('input[name="LoginForm\[password\]"]');
$password->value('123456');
```